# NextJS 13 - how to get NextApiRequest object in async component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

According to the NextJS 13 documentation, writing the async components is the new way of prefetching some data on the server - all the `getStaticProps`, `getInitialProps`, and `getServerSideProps` should be replaced by async components.

My problem is that I have a situation where I need to access the `path` in order to prefetch some data (I am loading metadata for the page from the server). Previously, I was using the `NextApiRequest` object that was passed as a parameter to the `getServerSideProps` function to retrieve the information about the path. I am unsure, however, how can I access this information in my async component.

I have tried to use the 'useRouter' hook to retrieve the `path` information, however hooks are not allowed on the Server components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, new feature added at v 13.2 [route-handlers](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers)

> A route.ts file can export an async function named by the HTTP verbs:
> GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE, and PATCH. These functions can
> then be wrapped and abstracted to create helpers / reusable logic for
> your custom route logic.
>
> Other server functions, like cookies and headers, can be used inside
> Route Handlers – along with any Web APIs these abstractions are built
> upon. This allows for code to be shared between Server Components and
> Route Handlers.

they also made an API change on `Metadata` as well. you can dynamically add metadata in each page file now. [next-13-2](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-2)

Answer (score 0):

in your api route, you can access the [NextRequest](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request) object

```js
// app/api/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
   // you can get `headers` `searchParams` `params` etc. from this request object
    return NextResponse.json({ id: 1, name: 'john doe'})
}

// app/page.tsx
async function getUser() {
 const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api')
 return res.json();
}

export default async function Page() {
  const user = await getUser();

  return <div>hello, {user.name}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not the NextRequest directly, you can access the headers and cookies. So you could do something like:

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";

type URLOptions = {protocol?: string;};

export function url(options?: URLOptions) {
const protocol = options?.protocol ?? "https";
const host = headers().get("host");
const path = headers().get("x-invoke-path");
const searchParams = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(headers().get("x-invoke-query") || ""),);

const url = new URL(`${protocol}://${host}${path}`);

Object.entries(searchParams).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((v) => url.searchParams.append(key, v));
      return;
    }
    url.searchParams.append(key, value as string);
});

    return url;
}
```